# Conditional looping in an Applicative Functor

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative

Suppose that `Parser x` is a parser that parses an `x`. This parser probably possesses a `many` combinator, that parses zero or more occurrences of something (stopping when the item parser fails).

I can see how one might implement that if `Parser` forms a monad. I can't figure out how to do it if `Parser` is only an Applicative Functor. There doesn't seem to be any way to check the previous result and decide what to do next (precisely the notion that monads add). What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Alternative` type class provides the `many` combinator:

```
class Applicative f => Alternative f where
    empty :: f a
    (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
    many  :: f a -> f [a]
    some  :: f a -> f [a]

    some = some'
    many = many'

many' a = some' a <|> pure []
some' a = (:) <$> a <*> many' a
```

1. The `many a` combinator means “zero or more” `a`.
2. The `some a` combinator means “one or more” `a`.

Hence:

1. The `some a` combinator returns a list of one `a` followed by `many a` (i.e. `1 + (0 or more)`).
2. The `many a` combinator returns either `some a` or an empty list (i.e. `(1 or more) | 0`).

The `many` combinator depends upon the `(<|>)` operator which can be viewed as the default operator in languages like JavaScript. For example, consider the `Alternative` instance of `Maybe`:

```
instance Alternative Maybe where
    empty = Nothing
    Nothing <|> r = r
    l       <|> _ = l
```

Essentially the `(<|>)` should return the left hand side value if it's truthy. Otherwise it should return the right hand side value.

A `Parser` is a data structure which is defined similarly to `Maybe` (the idea of [applicative lexer combinators](http://www.holdermans.nl/pubs/assets/holdermans13fast.pdf) and parser combinators is essentially the same):

```
data Lexer a = Fail | Ok (Maybe a) (Vec (Lexer a))
```

If parsing fails, the `Fail` value is returned. Otherwise an `Ok` value is returned. Since `Fail <|> pure []` is `pure []`, this is how the `many` combinator knows when to stop and return an empty list.

Comment: For me, the key point is that the "decision" is implemented using `<|>`. I don't know why I didn't figure that out...

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done just by using what is provided by `Applicative`. But `Alternative` has a function that gives you power beyond `Applicative`:

```
(<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
```

This function lets you "combine" two `Alternatives` without any restriction whatsoever on the `a`. But how? Something intrinsic to the particular functor `f` must give you a means to do that.

Typically, `Alternative`s require some notion of failure or emptiness. Like for parsers, where `(<|>)` means "try to parse this, if it fails, try this other thing". But this "dependence on a previous value" is *hidden* in the machinery implementing `(<|>)`. It is not available to the external interface, so to speak.

From `(<|>)`, one can implement a zero-or-one combinator:

```
optional :: Alternative f => f a -> f (Maybe a)
optional v = Just <$> v <|> pure Nothing
```

The definitions of `some` an `many` are similar but they require mutually recursive functions.

Notice that there are `Applicative`s that aren't `Alternative`s. You can't make the `Identity` functor an `Alternative`, for example. How would you implement `empty`?

Comment: does that mean that Alternative is equal in power to Monad?

Comment: @WillNess only if you could tabulate all types. To see why, to implement `(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)` with `<|>`, you basically need to `foldr (<|>) empty` over a list where  each item consists of checking that the dependee result matches one particular `a` value, and then degenerates to `m b`. So to be able to do that for all choice of `a`, you'd need to be able to tabulate all `a -> m b` functions.

Answer (score 1):

`many` is a class method of the `Alternative` class [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2) which suggests that an general applicative functor does not always have a `many` implementation.